# ¿Cómo llamar una vista de otro controlador YII2?

Tags: yii2

Comunidad:

Mi problema surge al querer llamar a una vista desde otro controlador, me encuentro en el index y con esto me muevo sin problemas dentro de la misma carpeta de vistas.

```
<?= Html::a('Contacto', ['contacto']) ?>
```

Esto llama a la función :

```
    public function actionContacto(){

     return $this->render('contactoform');

   }
```

Esto normalmente funciona, pero el problema es que **contactoform** se encuentra en la carpeta de las vistas de **Contacto**.

¿Cómo le hago? Ayuda D:

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar el nombre de la carpeta de la vista en el método `render` (Que corresponde con el nombre del controlador en minúscula).

Quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
public function actionContacto(){
     return $this->render('/contacto/contactoform');
}
```

Se agregó `/contacto/`.